# Why do I get duplicate variables in my post result when submitting a WTForm in Flask after setting the hidden field values in the view component?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

When I set the value of the the hidden fields in the view component and submit the form the POST variable on the other end returns two instances of each variable where the first one is empty but the second holds the expected data. I can't seem to be able to retrieve or pop the data from the POST variable (which is an ImmutableMultiDict type). If I cast the POST to a dict I loose the second variables including the data. Also if I try to iterate through the POST variable and build a dictionary the second variable is not copied. So basically I can't get the POST data even if I would accept this duplicity.

I'm using Flask and WTForms in a traditional MVC architecture.

**forms.py :**

```
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
   the_int = HiddenField()
   the_string = HiddenField()
   the_list = HiddenField()
   the_dict = HiddenField()
   submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**routes.py :**

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    an_int = 1
    a_string = "ABC"
    a_list = ['One', 'Two']
    a_dict = {'First': 'A', 'Second': 'B'}
    form = TestForm()
    return render_template('test.html', an_int = an_int,
                                        a_string = a_string,
                                        a_list = a_list,
                                        a_dict = a_dict,
                                        form = form)


@app.route('/testresult', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def testresult():
    if request.method == "POST":
        formdata = request.form
        dictdata = dict(request.form)
        builtdata = {}
        for k, v in request.form.items():
            builtdata.update({k: v})
        return render_template('testresult.html', formdata = formdata,
                                                  dictdata = dictdata,
                                                  builtdata = builtdata)
    return render_template('test')
```

**test.html :**

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<br>
<form action="testresult" method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.the_int(value=an_int) }}
    {{ form.the_string(value=a_string) }}
    {{ form.the_list(value=a_list) }}
    {{ form.the_dict(value=a_dict) }}
    {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

**testresult.html :**

```
<h1>Result</h1>
<p>{{ formdata }}</p>
<p>{{ dictdata }}</p>
<p>{{ builtdata }}</p>
```

**Result in testresult.html :**

```
Result

ImmutableMultiDict([('the_int', ''), ('the_int', '1'), ('the_string', ''), ('the_string', 'ABC'), ('the_list', ''), ('the_list', "['One', 'Two']"), ('the_dict', ''), ('the_dict', "{'First': 'A', 'Second': 'B'}"), ('csrf_token', 'IjN---kWw'), ('submit', 'Submit')])

{'the_int': '', 'the_string': '', 'the_list': '', 'the_dict': '', 'csrf_token': 'IjN---kWw', 'submit': 'Submit'}

{'the_int': '', 'the_string': '', 'the_list': '', 'the_dict': '', 'csrf_token': 'IjN---kWw', 'submit': 'Submit'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `form.hidden_tag()` renders all the hidden fields in your form. You are also rendering your hidden fields manually, so they end up getting defined twice.

Here is the [documentation on hidden_tag](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.hidden_tag).

The correct way to code your template would be:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<br>
<form action="testresult" method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

To insert values into your hidden fields, do it in the view function:

```py
    form = TestForm()
    form.the_int.data = an_int
    form.the_string.data = a_string
    form.the_list.data = a_list
    form.the_dict.data = a_dict
    return render_template('test.html', form = form)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Miguel. I obviously failed to mention that in my view (html) I want to iterate through a list and create (various) number of forms of the same kind where each submit button sends different POST data. I fail to see how this can be done in the view function.

Comment: Based on your comment I figured out that my problem can be "fixed" by not calling form.hidden_tag() but then I lack the CSRF token. I also figured out that I can call form.hidden_tag() after setting the hidden values and then I have the empty values later in the POST variable. But I expect there is a better way to perform this. Can you comment on this @Miguel ?

Comment: I don't see why it would be different if you have more than one form. I believe I answered your question as you asked it with a solution that works. If you have a different question related to having multiple forms then maybe you should write another question and show a more accurate example of the situation you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

As Miguel's explained, you're seeing duplicates because you're using

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```

in your template and as you've discovered, you lose the CSRF token when you omit it.  That said, you can manually add the CSRF token back in as a hidden as a hidden field by using

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
```

This approach won't interfere with your iterating through a list of custom hidden form fields.

https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html